# How can one fulfill wishes through rituals?

Tags: rituals, temple, vrata, japa, tapasya

Are there rituals (including *vrat*, *tapa*, *japa*, *anusthan*, *purasharan*,etc) through which one can fulfill one's wishes and overcome obstacles?

Answer (score 1):

1. Citing from ***Chandogya-upanishad***, chanting AUM/OM fulfills ones desires.

> तद्वा एतदनुज्ञाक्षरं यद्धि किंचानुजानात्योमित्येव तदाहैषो एव
> समृद्धिर्यदनुज्ञा समर्धयिता ह वै कामानां भवति य एतदेवं
> विद्वानक्षरमुद्गीथमुपास्ते ॥ १.१.८ ॥
>
> tadvā etadanujñākṣaraṃ yaddhi kiṃcānujānātyomityeva tadāhaiṣo eva
> samṛddhiryadanujñā samardhayitā ha vai kāmānāṃ bhavati ya etadevaṃ
> vidvānakṣaramudgīthamupāste || 1.1.8 ||
>
> That akṣaram [Om] stands for assent. A person says Om whenever he
> wants to say yes. This Om is the key to progress. **He who worships Om
> as the udgītha [Brahman]**, knowing it thus [as the fulfiller of all
> desires], **has all his desires fulfilled**.

2. Citing from ***Shiva Purana*** which simply states to recite *Rudra Samhita* 3 times before the image of *Bhairava*:

[image]